# How do you bind to a listbox.itemtemplate in a style's content template content control

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, blend, itemtemplate

I basically have this situation:

```
<Style x:Key="MyListBoxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                        <!-- style stuff-->
                    </ContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 </Style>
```

and this ListBox in a separate file

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}" ItemsContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyListBoxItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But when we run it, the listbox only shows .ToString(). It does not bind properly. How do I get the ItemTemplate to hook up properly with the contentcontrol content property?

I have a suspicion I might be doing something very wrong.

Comment: have you tried just taking out the `ItemContainerStyle`? does it work fine then? I don't get why you need to use Style elements for the `Content` within `ItemContainerStyle`. That's the reason you got the `ItemTemplate` property to deal with. Keeping `ItemContainerStyle` to just deal with the Container related styling is what I'd go for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ListBoxItem style add ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"

```
<ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}">
                                    <!-- style stuff-->
                                </ContentControl>
```